# VMware with the HP MSA70

Tags: storage-area-network, hp, direct-attached-storage

I would like to build a new smallish VMware cluster - only two nodes will ever be used.

I have previously seen references to shared direct attached storage. That would dramatically push down the price point. Instead of going with an MSA2000 or a LeftHand SAN can the HP MSA70 be used in this fashion? Any caveats I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the [HP StorageWorks MSA70](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12652_na/12652_na.html) is an older product. It's since been replaced by the [HP StorageWorks D2700](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13404_na/13404_na.html).

Either way, both products are meant to be used as direct-attached storage to an *individual* server, or cascaded from a SAN unit like the P2000.

You have some options, though. [I build storage servers that connect to such an enclosure](http://mail.opensolaris.org/pipermail/zfs-discuss/2011-November/050418.html) (using [NexentaStor](http://nexentastor.org/)), then share the storage to VMWare hosts via iSCSI or NFS. You could also look into a [SAS-based HP P2000 G3 unit](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13551_na/13551_na.html), which can provide direct-attached SAS connectivity to up-to four servers.

Comment: After a week of telling me to put NexentaStor on a box instead of getting a pair of P4500s, you neglect to recommend it in this answer?!?!?!?!?

Comment: "I build storage servers that connect to such an enclosure..."

Comment: Just poking fun :D

Comment: Thanks ewwhite. I built out a couple Linux iSCSI targets as well.. Was hoping for a cheap server grade hardware solution. I'm not partial to the SAS interface. Looks like either a P2000 or a MSA2000 may be in my future.

Comment: P2000 G3 is the current SAS/iSCSI/FC product from HP. If you have a spare server, you could connect it to the MSA70 or D2700 and service storage via NFS/iSCSI. I recommend NexentaStor for that, but Linux also works (just not as well).

Comment: I'm partial to the P2300 units myself; they're rock solid and pretty easy to configure. Nothing against NexentaStor, though creating a redundant cluster can be pricey.